# Remove multiple listview items on button with checkbox

Tags: android, listview, button, checkbox, delete-row

I've searched around for this problem. I started coding some days ago and I'm trying to create a dynamic listview where you can add strings and remove them by checking checkboxes and removing checked options.

This code works, however it can only remove **multiple** items if they're checked from top to bottom. If I start checking the bottom one, and then check the top one, it only deletes the top one. If i check all boxes from bottom to top, it removes top and bottom. If i check middle one without checking anything else first, it removes it correctly.

Please provide any help you can.

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);


    //listview

    //add items
    questions.add("Jag har aldrig");
    questions.add("Jag har aldrig varit");
    questions.add("Jag har aldrig2");

    //Checkboxadapters
    final ListView questionList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.questionList);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, questions);
    if(questionList != null) {
        questionList.setAdapter(adapter);
        questionList.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        questionList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        /*questionList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {  //LISTENER
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView)view;
                if(ctv.isChecked()){
                    Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, "now it is checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, "now it is unchecked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });*/
    }


    //Erasebutton listener
    final Button eraseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eraseButton);
    assert eraseButton != null;
    eraseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //erasebutton onclick
        public void onClick(View eraseButton) {
            assert questionList != null;
            SparseBooleanArray checked = questionList.getCheckedItemPositions();
            for(int i=0; i < questionList.getCount(); i++)
            {
                if(checked.get(i)) {
                    //What to do with selected listitems
                    String item = (String) questionList.getAdapter().getItem(i);
                    Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, String.format("Removed: %s",item), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    adapter.remove(questions.get(i));
                }
            }
            checked.clear();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });



    //Nextbutton listener
    final Button returnButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.returnButton);
    assert returnButton != null;
    returnButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //Nextbutton onclick
        public void onClick(View returnButton) {
            Intent mainMenu = new Intent(Main3Activity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            Main3Activity.this.startActivity(mainMenu);
        }
    });


}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you remove item, total count changes and other items shifted so your loop correctly deletes only first checked item from list view. You may try to change direction of your loop:

```
for(int i = questionList.getCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if(checked.get(i)) {
                //What to do with selected listitems
                String item = (String) questionList.getAdapter().getItem(i);
                Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, String.format("Removed: %s",item), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                adapter.remove(questions.get(i));
            }
        }
```

some illustration how your loop works:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Changing the direction of the loop solved the deletion issue.

If you do have the time, please explain further why changing the direction did solve the problem as it would teach me more about loops in general and prevent future problems.

Also, when I add adapter.notifyItemRemoved(i) in the loop, it can not resolve the method. Did I forget to add something on initialization of the adapter?

Comment: notifyItemRemoved is for RecyclerView.Adapter, not for your case - my mystake. I edited my answer and added some illustration of your loop. I hope it will help you understand.

Comment: Most kind regards to you! Thank you.